# Bootstrap Table load method work in firefox not in chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4, bootstrap-table

I'm building a php application with laravel. Certain function works perfectly in firefox. But it doesn't work sometimes in chrome. I use wenzhixin bootstrap table.

```
$.post("{{ route('knitting.table', ['requestingDepartment' => 'Warping' , 'workdone' => 0]) }}", { _token: token } ,function(){})
.done(function(data1) {
    $('#table1').bootstrapTable('load', data1);
});
```

This is the code i use within jquery load function.
There are four tables like this in a single page. When i run this code in firefox, all four tables get loaded  with the data from the server. But if i run it on chrome, sometimes it loads all the tables. But most of the times one or more tables don't get loaded and i get this error in the webconsole.

*Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapTable is not a function*

How's this possible?

And I have another problem, when i run the same code to load the table with the code *$.ajax()* It doesn't work in firefox either, I get the same error as i get in chrome.

Please give a solution for this problem. Loading the tables with data from the server is the heart of this system. What do i miss?